# How I can manage free gift in woocommerce e.g. buy 10 get 1 free

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I give 1 free gift to a customer who has purchased 10 products? Can you provide me a demo link or demo video of how to achieve this in Woocommerce? Please solve this query.
How to make free gift shipping in cart and checkout pages?

**I have solution for buy per 10 product and get 1 product.** After buying 100 products he/she gets 10 free product. I need a useful plugin or source code; it may free or paid.

Comment: Your question is too broad please add more detail and include your relevant code.

Comment: I have not got clear answer from your side. I need when a person purchase 9 product he/she not get free product but he/she buy 10-19 product they got 1 free products in selected category, and when they buy 20,30,40.. etc products they got 2,3,4.., and lastly they purchase 100 products they got 10 product..  I need to show all free product add in checkout page after cart page proceed.

Comment: This is potentially a good question, but it's badly written ... if there's any way you can make it clearer it might more answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin called [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) made by WooThemes enables you to set discounts based on purchases. You could do it so when they purchase 10 products, they can get a 100% discount to a certain product. There is also a "Special Offer Advanced Category Pricing" Where you can set how many products they have to buy to get X number free. See docs here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing/

Comment: But I have want to free product not discount.

Comment: 100% off = free. You call it whatever you want on the front-end. That's what free means in eCommerce terms.

Comment: I have not got clear answer from your side. I need when a person purchase 9 product he/she not get free product but he/she buy 10-19 product they got 1 free products in selected category, and when they buy 20,30,40.. etc products they got 2,3,4.., and lastly they purchase 100 products they got 10 product..  I need to show all free product add in checkout page after cart page proceed.

Comment: There are also another plugin for this purpose like http://ankitpokhrel.com.np/blog/downloads/woocommerce-multiple-free-gift-plugin-pro/